# Scattering matrix elements for potential $q(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, s-matrix-theory

Suppose I have  S.E. with potential $q(x)$, which is known, how do I compute the scattering or S-matrix with respect to this potential?

I've tried searching for non-trivial (i.e constant potential steps/barrier/wells etc) examples, but nowhere do I find a concrete sequence of steps to do a computation of the matrix elements of S.

To be specific: suppose I have the following:

$$-\psi''(x) + q(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$$

with a fixed potential $q(x)$, and furthermore suppose all the solutions of the S.E above are known. With the usual setup:

$$\psi_{L}(x) = A(k)e^{ikx} + B(k)e^{-ikx}$$
$$\psi_{R}(x) = C(k)e^{ikx} + D(k)e^{-ikx}$$

In literature, it says that the $S$ matrix relates the $B,C$ coefficients to the $A,D$ coefficients and gives "all information about the scattering".

What I want to know is how these coefficients, $A,B,C,D$ and the $S$ matrix depend on the potential and solutions of the given S.E above. That is, what do I need to compute?

Comment: There is no closed-form solution. You  have to solve the Shroedinger equation, and there is no general solution for a 2nd order ODE.

Comment: Suppose I know all the solutions, as I stated.

Comment: If you know the solutions, then you know that a  solution that $\psi_{k}(x)$  that is of the form  $T(k)e^{ikx}$ to the right of the potential looks like $e^{ikx} +R (k) e^{-ikx}$ when evaluated on  the left.  Here the transmission coefficient $T(k)$ and reflection coefficient $R(k)$ are functions that you found in the process of solving the equation.   Maybe, however you want the S matrix in terms of  in and out states instead?  In that case it helps if $q(x)$ is left-right symmetric so that  an odd or even incoming wave is just phase shifted. I'll add an "anwer with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once  you know $A(k)$ $B(k)$ $C(k)$ and $D(k)$ then the S-matrix converts the incoming waves --- $A$ from the left and $D$ from the right---  to the ougoing waves $B$ to the left  and $C$ to the right as 
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} B \cr C\end{matrix}\right)= \left(\begin{matrix} S_{11} & S_{12}\cr S_{21} &S_{22}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} A \cr D\end{matrix}\right).
$$
So to find the first column you chose boundary condition $A=1$, $D=0$ and read off $S_{11}, S_{21}$from you solution. Similarly the second column.

Comment: I failed to understand was how the choice of potential and hence the solutions affect the structure of the scattering matrix. Thanks to your answer however, I realized that if I know the potential, and how solutions look on the right and left, than I am given equations for the relations between, A,B,C,D and hence the S-matrix  is, as you mention, easily constructed. Thanks.